# bus travel from Oslo airport to oslo bus station

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, buses, oslo, osl

I will be travelling from Oslo Gardemoen airport to oslo , as I probably won't clear customs until about midnight I will have missed the last train. Is it possible to use a credit card to pay for the bus

Answer (score 3):

You can both buy the bus ticket online on [Flybussen's home page](https://www.flybussen.no/billett/#/reise/fra/oslo-flyplass/osl) (NOK 189) or buy a ticket from the bus driver, but you will then have to pay a surcharge. In both cases you can pay by credit card. The bus takes about 50 minutes to reach the bus terminal in the city centre close to the main railway station.

If you get through customs around midnight, you will however have plenty of time to reach one of the last trains, which are substantially faster. There is just a couple of minutes walk from the customs exit to the train platforms. The last regular suburban train departs 23:43, is a 23 minute trip to the main railway station and costs NOK 105. There are further departures with the airport express train 23:50, 0:10, 0:30 and 0:50, which take 22 minutes and cost NOK 196. You can buy train tickets at the ticket machines at the airport and pay with credit card. Be aware of different ticket machines for the regular train and for the express train.

If you want, you can also buy train tickets in advance. Tickets for the regular train are available on [Vy's home page](https://www.vy.no/en), while tickets for the express train can be bought on [Flytoget's home page](https://flytoget.no/en/). On the regular train, you can also buy a ticket from the train conductor and pay by card, but you will also there have to pay a surcharge. On the airport express train, you can also travel ticket-less by swiping your credit card at the entrance barriers when entering and leaving the train.

Comment: Is there a typo in those timings, or are people really paying NOK 91 extra to get there _one minute faster_?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The travel times and prices are indeed correct. The regular trains depart less frequently. During the day time there are three departures per hour: x:03, x:13 and x:43, while the express trains have six departures per hour: x:00, x:10, x:20, x:30, x:40 and x:50. The express trains also start operating earlier in the morning and continue later in the evening than the other trains, but in most cases the only advantage you get from paying almost twice the price for a ticket is that you might catch an earlier train.

Comment: @christopherknowles If this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the check box below the voting buttons.